# Linking to pdf in public/ directory in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, pdf, create-react-app

I'm looking to place a small amount of pdf files in my public/ directory in my React app created with create-react-app.

Something similar to the directory structure below:

```
public/
 - dir/
 -- a.pdf
 -- b.pdf
```

However, the links seem to be broken in prod when referencing them as `<a href="dir/a.pdf"></a>`, while working fine in my local dev environment. So I have a few questions:

1. Is it bad practice and/or unsupported to host pdf files in "public/"?
2. If not, is there an appropriate way to reference these files so that they work both on localhost and in a production / hosted environment (AWS Amplify in this case)?

Ideally, these files would be hosted elsewhere (e.g. AWS S3) and imported, especially in the case where the number of files is large. However, I'm looking to do this to save time and reduce the number of dependencies / setup for this small project.

Comment: Have you tried with "/dir/a.pdf"? It's good to keep your assets in public as they are not files needed to be processed for your build, plus it should work for both local and production environments

Answer (score 0):

Why not hosting your app, and files in s3, since it's static, I suppose you're not doing server-side rendering, this will keep things simple.